# Optapy : Use toList function on group by from two joined classes - TypeError : No matching overloads

Tags: group-by, constraints, typeerror, optaplanner, optapy

I am currently working on an employee rostering problem in which one constraint's goal is to avoid gaps in an employee schedule using a constraint stream. The idea is to get for each employee the timeslots they are assigned to along with their availability, retrieve those informations in a list, then perform the check on the returned list. 
The constraint stream is as following :

```python
def continuous_shifts(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory, score = HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD):
    return constraint_factory \
        .for_each(timeslot_assignment_class) \
        .join(availability_class, [
            Joiners.equal(
                lambda timeslot_assignment : timeslot_assignment.resource.resource_id,
                lambda availability : availability.resource.resource_id
            )
        ]) \
        .group_by(lambda timeslot_assignment, availability : timeslot_assignment.resource.resource_id,
                lambda timeslot_assignment, availability : availability.resource.resource_id,
                ConstraintCollectors.to_list()) \
        .penalize("holes in schedule",score,lambda timeslot_list : holes_in_list(timeslot_list))
```

What I want to do is to join the timeslot_assignment with the availabilities based on the resource_id attribute, group them by resource (i.e. employee) then return those groups in lists in which I can test gaps in schedule in the penalize part.
I have to use a join on the availability class because they are not contained as an attribute in resources and are stored separately for navigation purposes.

The main struggle I am having is in returning a list in the group by function. In the showed case, I got this error :

> TypeError: No matching overloads found for org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.bi.DroolsAbstractBiConstraintStream.groupBy(proxy.PythonBiFunction,proxy.PythonBiFunction,org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.DefaultUniConstraintCollector),

Followed by a list of suitable options for ConstraintCollectors. 
As I read in other posts, I understood that there can be overload issues with functions used with ConstraintCollectors and that the types might have to be manually specified. I tried other combinations like casting the lambda functions to java BiFunctions, or changing the group by function like this :

```
.group_by(lambda timeslot_assignment, availability : (timeslot_assignment.resource.resource_id,availability.resource.resource_id),
    ConstraintCollectors.to_list())
```

which changed the error message according to the modified classes/stream cardinality but with no improvement. I also tried swapping the `to_list` function for `toList` which resulted in no change.

I can't figure out if the problem comes from the way I joined/grouped or if this is more of a type issue in which some types have to be specified.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My advice is to not use a `toList()` collector, or any other that groups into a collection. This is a performance killer. If you are looking for gaps between assignments, select 2 assignments, check that no other assignment exist between them, and then compare the two.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `to_list()` is actually `to_list(lambda x: x)`, which is a `UniConstraintCollector`, and thus can only be used with `UniConstraintStream` (that is, a constraint stream of only one element). You have a `BiConstraintStream`, so `to_list()` will not work. What will work is `to_list(lambda x, y: (x, y))`, which is a BiConstraintCollector (and thus will work with `BiConstraintStream`). Thus, the constraint stream should look like this:

```
def continuous_shifts(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory, score = HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD):
    return constraint_factory \
        .for_each(TimeslotAssignment) \
        .join(Availability,
             Joiners.equal(
                lambda timeslot_assignment : timeslot_assignment.resource.resource_id,
                lambda availability : availability.resource.resource_id
             )
        ) \
        .group_by(ConstraintCollectors.to_list(lambda timeslot_assignment, availability : (timeslot_assignment.resource.resource_id,availability.resource.resource_id))) \
        .penalize("holes in schedule",score,lambda timeslot_list : holes_in_list(timeslot_list))
```

Note: `optapy` no longer require usage of `get_class`; you can directly use the relevant Python classes. Additionally, casting is no longer required for group by's, and you don't need to pass Joiners as a list. (although the old code will still work).

```
def continuous_shifts(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory, score = HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD):
    return constraint_factory \
        .for_each(TimeslotAssignment) \
        .join(Availability,
             Joiners.equal(
                lambda timeslot_assignment : timeslot_assignment.resource.resource_id,
                lambda availability : availability.resource.resource_id
             )
        ) \
        .group_by(ConstraintCollectors.to_list(lambda timeslot_assignment, availability : (timeslot_assignment.resource.resource_id,availability.resource.resource_id))) \
        .penalize("holes in schedule",score,lambda timeslot_list : holes_in_list(timeslot_list))
```

Like Lukas said, `to_list` is a performance killer. If you are looking for singular gaps, I suggest looking at the OptaPy employee scheduling quickstart, in particular the ["at least two hours between two shifts" constraint.](https://github.com/optapy/optapy-quickstarts/blob/04fd102ee31919cacc4145d0517fe07b2627ca02/employee-scheduling/constraints.py#L56-L68)

In regards to finding (global) consecutive shifts and breaks in shifts (i.e. need to penalize/reward based on a non-linear function on the number of consecutive shifts/breaks); that is best done using a `ConstraintCollector`; there is currently an experimental one in `optaplanner-examples`, but that is not accessible to `optapy`. Once that collector is available in `optaplanner-core`, it will also be available in `optapy`. You cannot create your own custom `ConstraintCollector` currently, but it will be available in a future version of optapy.